# Foundation 6 Mega Menu and Responsive Toggle Navigation with Drilldown Title Bar on Small

Tags: zurb-foundation, megamenu

I want to create a full-width dropdown mega menu that I can also combine with a top bar that has an drilldown menu in mobile screens. Any method I've tried on Foundation only works with Foundation 5, since they changed top bar in Foundation 6.

So far, (with the help from this thread: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36800-f6-and-mega-menus) I have been able to create the dropdown mega menu and on small screens, the title bar appears and toggles open. However, when I try to open an item with a drilldown submenu, it still treats it as though it is a dropdown item.

Also, I am noticing that full-width hover for the submenus are somehow pushing the screen to a lot of extra empty space horizontally. While I can get rid of the extra empty horizontal space by adding a max-width:100% to the dropdown-pane class, the second of my two mega submenus doesn't display full-width correctly when I hover over them. Although in the codepen, they show just fine.

This is the link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/jen188/pen/PzRkbg

This is the code for my header;

```
<header>
    <div class="row columns expanded">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="img/REPLogo.png" alt="Real Estate Promo" class="logo show-for-small-only" /></a>
      <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
        <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
        <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
      </div>

      <div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
        <div class="top-bar-left"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/REPLogo.png" alt="Real Estate Promo" class="logo hide-for-small-only" /></div>

        <div class="top-bar-right">
          <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal expanded dropdown menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events Calendar</a></li>
            <li class="has-submenu is-drilldown-submenu-parent">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown" data-toggle="megamenu-resources">Resources
                <div class="dropdown-pane" id="megamenu-resources" data-dropdown data-options="closeOnClick:true; hover: true; hoverPane: true">
                  <div class="row column expanded">
                    <div class="large-9 columns">
                      <div class="row column expanded">
                        <div class="large-4 columns">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><h3>Foreclosure Laws</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/laws.png" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="large-4 columns">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="lenders.html"><h3>Hard Money Lenders</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/coin-stack.png" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="large-4 columns">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="glossary.html"><h3>Real Estate Glossary</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="large-3 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><h3>Find a REIA</h3></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/map-icon.png" alt="Click for More Info"/></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Find a REIA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="Click for More Info"/></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div> -->
                    <!-- <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">

                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="lenders.html">Hard Money Lenders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="Click for More Info"/></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="glossary.html">Real Estate Glossary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="Click for More Info"/></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu is-drilldown-submenu-parent">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown" data-toggle="megamenu-property-listings">Property Listings
                <div class="dropdown-pane" id="megamenu-property-listings" data-dropdown data-options="closeOnClick:true; hover: true; hoverPane: true">
                  <div class="row column expanded">
                    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">All Properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Single Family Properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Multi Family Properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu is-drilldown-submenu-parent">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown" data-toggle="megamenu-websites">Get a Website
                <div class="dropdown-pane" id="megamenu-websites" data-dropdown data-options="closeOnClick:true; hover: true; hoverPane: true">
                  <div class="row column expanded">
                    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x250" alt="Click for More Info" /></a></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie ullamcorper nisl, sit amet tristique est dapibus nec.</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `width:100%`, and `max-width:100%`,
Instead use `width:auto`, and `left:0px !important` and all things work fine.